# Matplotlib does not work with Canopy 1.3 on Linux Mint Debian Edition

Tags: python, linux, matplotlib, enthought, canopy

I recently upgraded to Canopy 1.3 on my Linux computer, and since then I am experiencing problems when trying to use Matplotlib. I did not have these problems with Canopy 1.1.

Invoking Matplotlib will always spawn an error like this:

```
>>> import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
>>> import numpy as np
>>> plt.plot(np.array([1,2,3]))


*** libmkl_p4m.so *** failed with error : /home/richard/Canopy/appdata/canopy-1.3.0.1715.rh5-x86/lib/libmkl_p4m.so: undefined symbol: i_free
*** libmkl_def.so *** failed with error : /home/richard/Canopy/appdata/canopy-1.3.0.1715.rh5-x86/lib/libmkl_def.so: undefined symbol: i_free
MKL FATAL ERROR: Cannot load neither libmkl_p4m.so nor libmkl_def.so
```

Apart from that, Canopy Python seems to be functioning normally.

This is on [Linux Mint Debian Edition (LMDE)](http://www.linuxmint.com/download_lmde.php) i386, a distribution that is based on Debian testing.

```
$ uname -a
Linux lmde-i386 3.11-2-486 #1 Debian 3.11.8-1 (2013-11-13) i686 GNU/Linux
```

I have already searched the Canopy/EPD support forums, but to no avail. ([This issue](https://support.enthought.com/entries/21656595-ImportError-libmkl-intel-lp64-so-cannot-open-shared-object-file) at first sight seemed to be related; but the proposed fixed does not help.) All I could find was a [posting in an Intel support channel](http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/mkl-fatal-error-cannot-load-neither-xxxx-with-intel-mkl-10x/), which indicates the problem might be due to incorrect linking.

Any hints would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Your installation of canopy is messed up, the error is telling you that numpy can not find some mkl libraries (mkl -> intel's optimized math libraries).  Try re-installing.  This would probably be better suited to superuser or linux/unix stacks (as this is an installation/linking error not a programming issue).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reinstalling (`~/Canopy`) is very unlikely to help. But resetting your user environment *might*. Delete `~/Enthought`, then restart the Canopy application to rebuild your user environment, then try again. If that fails, please email support@enthought.com with a reference to this SO question.

Comment: Removing ~/Enthought and restarting Canopy to set up the user environment actually fixed the problem. Thanks for your help!